# Silverlight control view image with zoom in/out?

Tags: silverlight

I wanna use an image viewer control in silverlight with feature zoom in/out the image, I found "**MultiScaleImage**" control that accept source as Xml file, which is can be created by "Deep Zoom Composer" program (install this program: import the images then expose and export: the program will generate the images and the "**dzc_output.xml**" file for you).

My Question is: I have a images(paths) that comes from the Database, how can I create the xml file at runtime without using the "Deep Zoom Composer" program!!!, I think this is impossible :(

Sooooooo anybody knows a silverlight control that I can use to **view image with zoom in/out**?????????

Answer (score 0):

In the Deep Zoom Composer program files directory, you will find DeepZoomTools.dll

Use that to generate your images and XML,